# Jquery Ui tabs url problem with page base

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a problem with jqueryui tabs.

I have this code :

```
//The jQuery Tabs
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();

//Code to open the correct tab if i write the hash on the url. It works fine
var hash = window.location.hash;
var index = $("#tabs a").index($('#link-'+hash.replace('#','')));
if(index>=0) $("#tabs a").eq(index).click();
```

It works fine if I don't put in the page **base href=...** I can open the tab in new page with right button of the mouse and the page opens with the correct tab selected.

If I put in my page  **base href=http://$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']/** When I open the tab in new window with the right button of the mouse, the page opened is incorrect. Only get the base of page, lose the most of url.

Help please. Sorry for my english

Comment: what do you mean by page base? Perhaps a small sample online would help me understand (jsFiddle) ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the

> If I put in my page /" />

bit,

but the two last lines could already be reduced to one i think:

```
$('#link-'+hash.replace('#','')).click();
```

Comment: the two last line get the hash from url and open the correct tab. It is not the problem. The problem is before, when i open a tab in new page, the link losts.